# Writing custom Gnome/Mate screensaver with SDL

Tags: gnome, linux-mint, screensaver, mate-desktop

I'm using MATE desktop environment on Linux Mint Nadia. I want to write my very own screensaver for mate-screensaver, but with SDL (not OpenGL).
I've been looking for solutions, found some usable source code [here](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-screensaver/tree/master/savers) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1583335). But the problem is that these screensavers are using OpenGL context, and because I don't know OpenGL nor GTK, I just can't replace the OpenGL parts with SDL. (a basic SDL_Surface to draw on would be more than enough for me)
If someone would help me I would be really glad!

(but please don't recommend me to use OpenGL, I have my reasons to use SDL)
Thanks!

Comment: can mate-screensaver (your question & first link) and gnome-screensaver (your second link) use the same customizations? mate-screensaver really needs more options; everyone uninstalls it as a result, usually replacing it with gnome-screensaver which has more options (themes). then there's the crowd that hates gnome-screensaver's limited options and installs xscreensaver. ...I'm not sure how or if a screensaver can be used/packaged for these different applications, so you may have to choose one first (mate/gnome/x), or explore if/how the saver could be used with multiple.

Comment: This link applies to gnome-screensaver & xscreensaver (but not mate-screensaver), and you can reuse things across these two ( https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions ).

Comment: sorry to spam your question with comments, but to answer my own question (from [here](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-screensaver/issues/5)) quoting/paraphasing: "mate-screensaver is a simplified front-end/daemon for xscreensaver" ... "[xscreensaver has] the daemon, the config front-end, and the 'hacks'. The first two are replaced by mate-screensaver...The 'hacks' ('themes' in the gnome docs, most people probably think of them as the 'screensavers themselves') used by mate-screensaver are the same as the ones used by xscreensaver." ... but mate lacks all the config options of xscreensaver

Answer (score -1):

Write you'r own screenlocker, and replace the gnome screensaver with it.

That's really the only thing i could recommend other than learning OpenGL, though I'm guessing you probably already thought of that.

Comment: Not really an answer, should've been a comment to the question.